# getImageData will not work with loaded images

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to load an image to a webpage and read a pixel value. Every reference describes the same use of getImageData, but while  it works nicely with pixels I write directly to the canvas (using fillRect), it cannot read *anything* after adding an image to the canvas. It simply crashes.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var imageObj1 = new Image();
imageObj1.src = "world_.png";
imageObj1.onload = function() {
 ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 500, 250);
 setTimeout(function() {
  alert("1");
  alert(ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1).data);
  alert("2");
 }, 100); // Adjust the delay time as needed
};
```

I added the setTimeout to take into account asynchronous loading times, but I have tried with and without that, and every other permutation or trick I can think of. *Nothing* works. The alerts simply stop after 1. I have tried with .png and .bmp versions of the image. All files are in the same directory on my laptop. It is run on Firefox 107.0. getImageData crashes it all, every time. And I have no idea why.